# How to update the user profile without having to fill the password and password_confirmation field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My **User** model is using `has_secure_password` (based on the [Rails tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)):

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "password_digest"
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :provider, :uid

  has_secure_password

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
```

And I have this edit view:

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

<%= f.label :avatar %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

Now the problem is that the user has to fill the `password` and `password_confirmation` field each time he/she wants to update the other fields.

So I was thinking of dividing the form:

**users/edit.html.erb:**

```
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :avatar %>
<%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

**users/edit_password:**

```
(I will add a current_password field later here).

<%= f.label :password, "New Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password,  %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password", "Retype Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

I'm thinking of two options:

1. Having all the user fields in each view, but making those fields I don't want the user to see hidden fields (the problem is that I can't retrieve the password for some reason. Something like `@user.password` returns `nil`. I can only do `@user.password_digest` but that won't validate the field).
2. Adding `:unless` in the `password` and `password_confirmation` validation (but I'm not sure how to do it so that it only applies to the `users/edit` view).

What's the best solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get user's password since the DB does not store it (it stores one-way encrypted password digest). So the second option is correct.

Take a look at Devise implementation ([validation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) and [controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)), it can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip validation by using object.save :validate=>false